# How to "slice" an std_logic_vector in VHDL?

Tags: syntax, vhdl

I'm developing a little thing in VHDL and am quite new to it. I'm having trouble figuring out how to slice a bigger std_logic_vector into a smaller one.

For instance I have 3 signals:

```
signal allparts: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal firstpart: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal secondpart: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
```

Basically, what I want is to assign bits 15 through 8 to `secondpart` and bits 7 through 0 to `firstpart`. How exactly would I "slice" a vector like this without assigning individual bits

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can directly assign them:

```
firstpart <= allparts(15 downto 8);
secondpart <= allparts(7 downto 0);
```

...or if firstpart and secondpart are simply alternate ways to refer to part of the allparts signal, you may want to use an alias:

```
alias firstpart is allparts(15 downto 8);
alias secondpart is allparts(7 downto 0);
```

Comment: Ah. I'm seeing more and more now that VHDL is a very consistent language. Also, the alias solution is much cleaner, so I'll use that

Comment: Note that for example `std_logic_vector([some expression])(15 downto 8)` won't work. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28452053/603003) for more detail when this syntax is applicable.