# signed to std_logic_vector, slice results

Tags: vhdl

I need to take the absolute value of a result and I am only interested in the most significant bits. This is what I have done:

```
data_ram_h <= std_logic_vector(abs(signed(resize(r4(calc_cnt - 2), data_ram_h'length) + r4(calc_cnt - 1) +
                    r4(calc_cnt) + r4(calc_cnt + 1) + r4(calc_cnt + 2) -
                    r2(calc_cnt - 2) - r2(calc_cnt - 1) - r2(calc_cnt) -
                    r2(calc_cnt + 1) - r2(calc_cnt + 2))))(11 downto 4);
```

I try to check the syntax and I get this error:

```
type conversion std_logic_vector is not allowed as a prefix for an slice name.
```

*data_ram_h* is a std_logic_vector of the right dimension, and the *abs* function returns a signed, to there shouldn't be problem in the conversion to std_logic_vector. The library I am using is use *ieee.numeric_std.all*.

Where am I wrong? Thanks in advance c:

Comment: As the error says: You can not slice the result of a function. You will need an intermediate signal or you can try to move the slice operation into your expression, which makes it even more unreadable.

Comment: @Paebbels thanks, what I couldn't get was that even std_logic_vector is a function! I posted my working solution.

Comment: If I'm correct std_logic_vector(..) is not a real function,but it does look like one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A type conversion is a basic operation that happens to require parentheses around it's operand expression.  And there's the rub, it's use is not a function call, so it can't be used as a prefix for a slice name.

A prefix for a slice name is either a function_call or a name. 
(IEEE Std 1076-2008, 5 Types, 5.1 General, explicit type conversion, 8 Names, 8.1 General, 8.5 Slice names).

If it was a function call you could slice the result.

On the other hand you can slice `"abs", so slice that and then do the type conversion:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity slice is
end entity;

architecture foo of slice is
    signal h_tmp: signed (11 downto 0);
    signal h_tmp_vec: std_logic_vector (11 downto 0);
    signal data_ram_h: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    signal calc_cnt:     integer := 3;
    type r_array is array (0 to 15) of unsigned(15 downto 0);
    signal r2, r4: r_array := (others => (others => '0'));
begin


    data_ram_h<= std_logic_vector (
                     "abs"(signed(resize(r4(calc_cnt - 2), data_ram_h'length) + r4(calc_cnt - 1) +
                      r4(calc_cnt) + r4(calc_cnt + 1) + r4(calc_cnt + 2) -
                      r2(calc_cnt - 2) - r2(calc_cnt - 1) - r2(calc_cnt) -
                      r2(calc_cnt + 1) - r2(calc_cnt + 2)))(11 downto 4)
                      );

end architecture;
```

Using `abs` as a function call requires you use it's declared name which is `"abs"`.

I'm just guessing at some declarations here, so I can't guarantee this works in your code.  The above example does analyze, elaborate and run which says the subtype ranges are compatible.

Comment: Thanks for explaining everything. I am going to read the part of the reference you pointed out in order to understand better!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved my doubt. Even `std_logic_vector` is a function, so I need 3 variables to slice the result without errors. Here what I did:

```
    h_tmp <= abs(signed(resize(r4(calc_cnt - 2), data_ram_h'length) + r4(calc_cnt - 1) +
                    r4(calc_cnt) + r4(calc_cnt + 1) + r4(calc_cnt + 2) -
                    r2(calc_cnt - 2) - r2(calc_cnt - 1) - r2(calc_cnt) -
                    r2(calc_cnt + 1) - r2(calc_cnt + 2)));
    h_tmp_vec <= std_logic_vector(h_tmp);
    data_ram_h <= h_tmp_vec(11 downto 4);
```

With the following definitions:

```
signal h_tmp: signed (11 downto 0);
signal h_tmp_vec: std_logic_vector (11 downto 0);
signal data_ram_h: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
```

Thanks Paebbels for your comment :)

If someone has a better way to solve it, please post it!

Comment: Is your calculation correct? Your are do a resize (unsigned extension) before a signed conversion.

Comment: @Paebbels it should be, I followed another answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382730/how-to-define-sum-results-width/28383429#28383429). All the registers are unsigned 8 bit, but I want the result after the sums/subtractions to be signed, in order to extract the absolute value.

Comment: And no std_logic_vector isn't a function, it's a basic operation which is why it can't be used in a slice name which requires the name of an array object or a function call that returns an array object.