# VHDL: Combining multiplication and slicing into one line

Tags: vhdl

I have a hardware accelerated function that requires two instances of fixed point multiplication. My current solution (example below) requires two clock cycles per multiplication; one step of multiplication, followed by a second step where that value is sliced back to the original input word size. I would like this to take as few cycles as necessary for latency.

Here is my current solution:

```
signal a        : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal b        : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal y        : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal product  : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    
MULTIPLY_PROCESS : process(clk) 
    begin
        if(rising_edge(clk)) then
            product <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) * unsigned(b));
            y <= product(11 downto 4);      --takes one additional clock cycle
        end if;                             --for y to appear
end process;
```

It makes sense to me that this could be shrunk down to one clock cycle, as normal unsigned multiplication does this automatically by throwing out the top end of the oversized vector.

example:

```
signal a    : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal b    : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal y    : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

MULTIPLY_PROCESS : process(clk)
    begin
        if(rising_edge(clk)) then
            y <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(a) * unsigned(b)); --truncates automatically
        end if;
end process;
```

This is code I thought would work, but throws a compiler error:

```
y <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(x) * unsigned(a))(11 downto 4)

Error: Prefix of slice name cannot be type conversion (STD_LOGIC_VECTOR) expression.
```

Is there some way to fixed-point multiply and truncate in a single line/step/clock cycle?

Comment: This could also be rephrased as a question around the error message. Mods feel free to change the title if you think that is better.

Comment: There is no relationship between fixed-point multiply and the semantic problem, the tag isn't useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [signed to std\_logic\_vector, slice results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28448701/signed-to-std-logic-vector-slice-results)

Comment: Here you can either move the assignment to signal product or signal y outside the clocked process either as a concurrent assignment statement or a sequential assignment in a process with a sensitivity list. There are other possible solutions, making product a process variable for instance or calling the function implementing the multiply overload operator -  `y <= std_logic_vector("*"(unsigned(a), unsigned(b))(11 downto 4));` which can be sliced.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The last line solves my issue specifically. Normally doing things outside a process or altering the sensitivity would work, but I am working on a synchronous block for a high speed device, so the input and output need to be on the same clock.

Comment: The question is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28448701/signed-to-std-logic-vector-slice-results). That showed up Googling your error message. Using Stackoverflow terms *[vhdl] Prefix type conversion slice* after slowly whittling out error message terms also finds the duplicate. There's an earlier question for essentially the same issue with an indexed name with the same answer. The semantic rules here are found in IEEE Std 1076-2008 8. Names, 8.1 General and 8.5 Slice names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to user1155120. Calling the multiplication through a function and then slicing the function before conversion does the trick.

```
y <= std_logic_vector("*"(unsigned(x), unsigned(a))(11 downto 4));
```

Comment: although it is easier to read if you keep them separate. Make "product" a variable and it doesn't take two cycles either. Make all these "unsigned" in the first place and lose the type conversions too, and it's clearer still.